# How to find optimal encomposing k-sided polygon for a set of points?

Tags: geometry, optimization

Given a set of 2-D points how to find encompassing k-sided polygon with minimal area when k is set?

Comment: If *N* is the total number of given points, find the $n\le N$ points from among them that form a convex polygon containing all other $N-n$ in its interior, or on its sides. How to find them ? Well, they have the property that a line through each such two *consecutive* points has all others situated in the same half-plane, i.e., by replacing *x* and *y* in the equation of that line with the two coordinates of each of the other $N-2$ point, all results will have the same sign. If $k=n$, then you're set. If $k>n$, then you have some leeway in adding extra points. The harder part is when $k<n$.

Comment: @Lucian And k < n is exactly the case :)

Comment: Then why did you not just ask directly how to determine the minimum-area *k*-sided *convex* polygon encompassing a random *n*-sided *convex* polygon, when $k<n$ ?